# Why JTextField.setText will fire DocumentListener's removeUpdate() before changedUpdate()?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField txt2 = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton btn = new JButton("Set Text");

    public Frame() {
        super("Latihan");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt1.setText("TEST"); txt2.setText("TEST2");
            }
        });

        txt1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new TheDocumentListener("txt1"));
        txt2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new TheDocumentListener("txt2"));

        add(txt1);
        add(txt2);
        add(btn);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Frame();
            }
        });
    }
}

class TheDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    private String source;

    public TheDocumentListener(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("insertUpdate from " + source);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("removeUpdate from " + source);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("changedUpdate from " + source);
    }
}
```

When I click on the JButton for the first time, only `insertUpdate()` will be called:

```
insertUpdate from txt1
insertUpdate from txt2
```

But if I click the button again, `removeUpdate()` will be called before `insertUpdate()`:

```
removeUpdate from txt1
insertUpdate from txt1
removeUpdate from txt2
insertUpdate from txt2
```

Is this expected behaviour or something wrong in my code?

Can I make `insertUpdate` the only method that was being called when performing `JTextField.setText`?  I want to make sure `removeUpdate` is being called only when user delete text in the text field.  How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of string replacement. What `setText()` actually does is remove the whole string and set a new one. Here is the implementation of `JTextField.setText()`:

```
public void setText(String t) {
    try {
        Document doc = getDocument();
        if (doc instanceof AbstractDocument) {
            ((AbstractDocument)doc).replace(0, doc.getLength(), t,null);
        }
        else {
            doc.remove(0, doc.getLength());
            doc.insertString(0, t, null);
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(JTextComponent.this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, `AbstractDocument.replace()` is executed for `AbstractDocument` docs. Otherwise, `remove()` and `insert()` are executed.

From [AbstractDocument.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) documentation:

> Deletes the region of text from offset to offset + length, and
>   replaces it with text. It is up to the implementation as to how this
>   is implemented, some implementations may treat this as two distinct
>   operations: a remove followed by an insert, others may treat the
>   replace as one atomic operation.

So it depends on the document implementation. `PlainDocument` for example inherits basic implementation of `AbstractDocument`. A `PlainDocument` is the default document for text fields.

You can always create you own document implementation if needed, or maybe installing a document filter. See [Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) tutorial for details. Not sure though, what is the reason behind this behavior change you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The reason is for simulating JTextField binding because setText() is not bound.  When it comes to mutual binding, it should be: change to other bound property will propagated to JTextField.text; and call to JTextField.text should be propagated to the bound property.  But what really happen now is change to JTextField.text will sometimes fire 1 or 2 document listener events and it's hard to decide when to stop the mutual binding.